# go build package path with absolute path

Tags: go

I am trying understand what "go build" does and so I enabled verbose flag

*go build -x -v -a hello.go*

For some packages I see that package path option has absolute directory name preceded by an '_'

*compile -o $WORK/b002/*pkg*.a -trimpath "$WORK/b002=>" -p _/users/someuser/Temp/HelloMe -complete -goversion go1.14.2 -D _/users/someuser/Temp/HelloMe -importcfg $WORK/b002/importcfg -pack -c=4 ./HelloMe.go*

In what cases does the build chain use such package path name and is there a way to specify something different?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to understand the whole go build process there's an excellent post on [Maori Geek](https://maori.geek.nz/how-go-build-works-750bb2ba6d8e) laying out a lot of the details. I believe you might be misinterpreting some of the arguments getting passed to the internal tools, but that post should help clear things up.

Answer (score -1):

> In what cases does the build chain use such package path name [...]

On Windows.

> and is there a way to specify something different?

No. (It doesn't matter anyway.)